# How can I change the login form's look in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am building a wordpress site for a client but my client wants to have a different look of login screen, so my question is how can i change the look of default wordpress login form's look. I don't want to change any core files, is there any way to change the look of the login form without changing the core files.
Any kind of help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without changing the core files, using the hook `login_head`, simply add these code inside your `functions.php` file and you are done

```
function custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
        h1 a { background-image:url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/yourImageFolder/login_logo.png) !important; }
    </style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login_logo');
```

**Update:** Also to change the link of the logo to the current site use following code snippet

```
function custom_login_url() {
    return get_bloginfo( 'siteurl' );
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'custom_login_url' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding the css. You can override the css by adding the following to your functions.php

```
/**
 * Login theme branding.
 */
function rt_login_css() 
{
    echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/css/login.css" />';
}
add_action('login_head', 'rt_login_css');
```

The logo uses css image background, so it can be overrided by css.

Basically, the login_head, hook is for the login page, and all I do is echo link to my login css file.

And from there, I use firebug to inspect what styles are being used.

The downside is you don't get complete control here, just whatever you can do with css and possible javascript.

Also here is an example of my css file:

```
h1 a { 
   background-image: url('/app/images/logo.png') !important; 
   width:330px; 
   height: 69px; 
   margin-bottom:0px; 
}

#login { 
   margin: 5em auto; 
}
```

All I do is change the logo, so it's pretty simple. Usually you'll have to make adjustments to align and space the logo correctly, which is what the other css is for here.

---

Additionally, you could consider creating your own login page and handle the authentication using various wordpress functions. This is more work, but you get full control over the look and feel of your login form.

Downside is that it is more work and also if a user gets redirected to the regular WP admin login page. So for that latter, I guess you'd have to do both.

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-login-page/ it seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the plugin [BM Custom Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bm-custom-login/) to customize the wordpress login box quickly and easily. By using this plugin you can:

1. Replace the wordpress logo with your custom image.
2. Can add a background color/image to the login page.
3. Can edit shadow/color option to the texts/links.
4. You can change admin footer text. (Appears at the bottom of the admin pages when logged in.)

This plugin will not change any core files